# Postgres insert query max length or number of VALUES parameters

Tags: postgresql, insert

I'm trying to find a way to speedup population of my db.

I'd like to use `COPY` as suggested [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html), but I have only access to my db, not to the entire server. All other tips worked good for me, but unfortunately I need another speedup now.

So now I'm using just an `INSERT ... VALUES` without autocommit or any constraints.
Maybe I'm totally wrong, but I noticed that when I'm trying to execute lesser number of queries with more values in VALUES, population goes faster.

So I'd like to know what is the query length limit (or VALUES parameters limit).

Comment: I can't find a limit in the documentation.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you can't use `COPY`? You can use that on a regular client connection just like `INSERT` (though you'll have to use the `FROM STDIN` variant, of course, rather than load from a file on the server).

Comment: Have a look at this excellent answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is that it depends on your system.  Eventually your client or server will run out of memory trying to process a huge statement. typical unimpressive hardware can handle a million (very skinny) rows without trouble.

The answer to your problem is that most widely used libraries have a way to use `COPY...FROM STDIN` which can be run from the client.  If you use psql, that mechanism is `\copy`.  In Perl's DBD::Pg, it is `pg_putcopydata`.